# Do i pay to hospitalize or let her go?

Tags: cats, health

I took my cat in this morning to have surgery on an impacted tooth, she is dripping pus & blood from her mouth & her face is swollen. Shes down to 4 lbs. So they call me and tell me they can't operate because shes in renal failure and wouldn't survive the anesthesia. They advised me to hospitalize her. I've only got $700, that buys me 3 days in hospital. She's a 9 yrs old persian. Are they just trying to make a buck or can this even be reversed?

Comment: What treatment are they proposing while the cat is hospitalized?

Comment: Catheterized in leg for fluids which is costing me 200 a day on 2nd day, 300 on 1st day, but i pick her up b4 they close so she doesnt stay alone since nobody is there. This is still considerd “hospitalization”.

Comment: They did that with my cat that also has kidney disease, so I think that's standard?  They only wanted to do that intensive treatment for I think three days, and after that we've had to give him subcutaneous fluids ourselves.  Kidney disease is always eventually fatal, but cats can live a substantial time with little kidney function, and not any pain. But it doesn't address the impacted tooth, which I worry is causing a lot of pain and possibly isn't going to get better without extraction. But, mind you, I'm not a vet, so I could be wrong.

Comment: The treatments do seem to help my cat, at any rate, as he lost quite a bit of weight before, but now he is gaining it back.